# Is every relavant calculation performed every time the page is loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, load

I have a model "Wrapper", which has_many of another model "Category", which in turn has_many of another model, "Thing".

"Thing" has the integer attributes `:count` and `:number`. It also has an instance method defined as such in `models/thing.rb`:

```
def ratio
  (self.count + self.number).to_f / Thing.all.count.to_f
end
```

"Category", then, has this instance method, defined in `models/category.rb`:

```
def thing_ratios
  self.things.sum(&:ratio.to_f)
end
```

Finally, my `wrapper.html.erb` view shows Categories, listed in order of `thing_ratios`:

```
<%= @wrapper.categories.all.order(&:thing_ratios).each do |category| %>
  ...
```

My question is this: every time someone reloads the page `wrapper.html.erb`, would every single relavant calculation have to be recalculated, all the way down to `self.count` for every Thing associated with every Category on the page?

Comment: Short answer: Yes! You might want to consider some view caching or counter caching.

Comment: @spickermann By 'view caching', are you talking about one of the three methods on this page? guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: What ever suits for you. @Kelseydh wrote a great answer with the different options you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the resources that @Kelseydh provided, you can also consider memoization for when you hit the same function multiple times as part of the same request. However, it will not retain its value after the request is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be recalculated every time. If this is an expensive operation you should add a counter_cache (guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) for the count and look into caching the query result using a service like memcache.

Many caching strategies exist, but for the database/Rails app itself Russian doll caching is considered the most flexible approach.  If your data doesn't update often (meaning you don't need to worry about cache expiration often) you may be able to get way with page caching -- if so, count yourself lucky.

#### Some resources to get you started:

DHH on Russian Doll Caching:  https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works).

Railscast on cache keys:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests

Advanced caching guide: http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_revised/

Not free, but I found this series was what really let me understand various forms of caching correctly:
http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/rails-4-1-performance-fundamentals

Comment: What if I added an attribute `some_attribute` to Category, and then defined an instance method in `category.rb` that performs all the relevant calculations and sets `some_attribute` equal to the result? Would the instance method run and update `some_attribute` every time someone visited the Category page?

Comment: @JoeMorano When you add a extra column to your models and update that colum after creation or update of an instance (or whatever might change the result) then that calculation would only happen once. All later page views just read that attribute and  do not have to recalculate. What makes this hard is not ensure that you do not forget to update that extra column if some changes.