# Is an instance variable recalculated every time it is used in the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm defining three instance variables in a controller. The last two use the value of the first one. Every time the first one is used to calculate another variable, does it have to be recalculated?

---

In other words, which method is faster here?

**Method 1**

```
def show
  @things = Thing.all.where(boolean: true)
  @things_decreasing = @things.reverse
  @things_random = @things.shuffle
end
```

**Method 2**

```
def show
  @things = Thing.all.where(boolean: true)
  @things_decreasing = Thing.all.where(boolean: true).reverse
  @things_random = Thing.all.where(boolean: true).shuffle
end
```

Comment: Unrelated: you can defer returning of the results in already randomized order to the database, by using `.order("random()")`, and thus eliminate the difference for `shuffle`. And for `reverse` and explicitly given `order`-clause, you can use `reverse_order`, and there will be absolutely no noticeable difference. Not that there is much :)

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same as your [other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28492404/479863)?

Comment: @muistooshort They're similar, but the other question was asking if calculations are performed upon every page load. This is asking if calculations are performed upon every new instance variable calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods will have almost the same performance, because `Thing.all.where(boolean: true)` returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. An `ActiveRecord::Relation` does not perform an database query immediately, but on the first method call that needs the data (`reverse` in this examples).

Method 2 creates new (but similar) relation objects, whereas Method 1 reuses the same relation object. There performance would be almost the same, because creating that relation is very fast compared to running multiple database calls and there is the same number of database call on both examples.

But there is a way to speed this up: Both methods in your example will only perform one database call, because Rails caches database calls in the database connector. But Rails will re-generate the result from that cached database responds on each query and will return an new array with new instances every time.

It might be faster (depending on the size of the database response) to load all objects into an array and to reuse that array:

```
def show
  # triggers the database call and returns an array (not a Relation)
  @things = Thing.where(boolean: true).to_a 

  # re-use the result from the @things array, and not a Relation object
  @things_decreasing = @things.reverse
  @things_random     = @things.shuffle
end
```

Comment: What if `@things` was defined with a complicated calculation? Would the server have to redo the calculation every time I use `@things` to calculate another variable?

Comment: That depends: Complex for the database, in the same method, in another method...? Can you add an example of what you mean by "was defined with a complicated calculation"?

Comment: Let's say `@things = (Thing.count.to_f / (1 + Thing.count).to_f )**3`. In that case, would `@things` have to recalculated for the calculations of `@things_decreasing` and `@things_random`?

Comment: That is a totally different usecase than the database example. In that case `@things` would hold the result (a number). That calculation would not be recalculated if you do something like: `foo = @things.succ`

Answer (score 0):

```
@things = Thing.where(boolean: true).to_a  
Benchmark.measure{@things_decreasing = @things.reverse}
```

Using Benchmark you can check the performance time. Its good to use the returned array for the sake of performance.

Comment: How would I use that? Does it return a value in my rails server?

Comment: You can use Benchmark command in your rails console. @JoeMorano Hope it works.